# Getting Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. while uploading a jar to nexus Repository

Tags: maven, devops, nexus

Getting Unauthorized.  error while uploading artifacts to Nexus Repository.

Please Help.......
***Full Error*** :

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project HelloWorldTest: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.LMB:HelloWorldTest:jar:1.0-20190704.125442-1 from/to FirstDevOpsProj_SnapShot (http://localhost:8089/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8089/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/LMB/HelloWorldTest/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorldTest-1.0-20190704.125442-1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

I tried with adding or removing (/) at the last of the Repository URL but didn't worked.

Below are the **Setting.xml**, **Pom.xml** and **Nexus Repository Summary** details
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
<proxies></proxies>
<servers>
   <server>
      <id>FirstDevOpsProj_SnapShot</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
<mirrors></mirrors>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>FirstDevOpsProj_SnapShot</id>
        <name>FirstDevOpsProj_SnapShot</name>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://localhost:8089/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.LMB</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorldTest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>HelloWorldTest</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>FirstDevOpsProj_SnapShot</id>
      <url>http://localhost:8089/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>default-deploy</id>
              <phase>deploy</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

```
Repository ID: snapshots
Repository Name: Snapshots
Repository Type: hosted
Repository Policy: Snapshot
Repository Format: maven2
Contained in groups: 
   Public Repositories


<distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <url>http://localhost:8089/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong.  I'd suggest running "mvn help:effective-settings" to make sure the settings.xml file is actually getting picked up.

Comment: Thanks rseddon, i tried the above command and it showing the build successful with the correct details and path  of settings.xml file.
But still couldn't found the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Is it just for this artifact or all artifacts? Did it work before? Can you upload a (non-snapshot) artifact using the same user ?

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for respond, actually it was setting.xml was pointing to wrong location after making that change it worked.